# Adding multiple event to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I searched stackoverflow but couldnt find a answer(sure there is one somewhere) but I am trying to add a activity for each listview input. I can manage it with one intent but how do I give each listview input  a seperate activity. So to be clear, I want to make every item have a serperate activity.

**Currently use this code to initiate a activity but want individual activities for each item.**

```
public class ListviewActivityActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_products);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BMICalculatorActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);


      }
    });
}
```

**Have tried adding this but it failed to work**

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_0 = 0;
          private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;
          private static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 2;


          protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
          {
              super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
              final Intent intent = new Intent();
              // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
              switch (position)
              {
                  case ACTIVITY_0:
                      intent.setClass(this, listview.activty.BMICalculatorActivity.class);
                      break;
                  case ACTIVITY_1:
                      intent.setClass(this, listview.activty.BodyLog.class);
                      break;
```

I know its probally simple to sort so any help would be amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this :

```
     Intent i = null;
     switch (position)
          {
              case ACTIVITY_0:
                  i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BMICalculatorActivity.class);
                  break;
              case ACTIVITY_1:
                  i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BodyLog.class);
                  break;
          }

      if(i != null)
      {
         startActivity(i);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          Intent i;

          // selected item
          String product = (String) lv.getItem(position);
          if(product.equals("photoshop"))
                        i = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, Photoshop.class);
          else if (product.equals("final cut pro"))
                        i = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, FinalCutPro.class);
          else
                        i = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, Generic.class);

          startActivity(i);


      }
    });
```

Another option would be to make a POJO that held the name of the listview entry and the class to call. And add an array of those instead of an array of Strings. This will require using an ArrayAdapter of some kind. Then when you get the Item, you simply call `startActivity(new Intent(listviewActivity.this, myPojo.classToCall);` You should be able to find a good example of that somewhere on SO...