# Add Intent to OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, addition

I have a listview ,I want that every button open different Activity.

listview there are many options,Each option will lead to another activity.

I didn't know how to do this.

Thanks.

Java

```
public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.adobe_products);

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mavo.class);

                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);

            }  });}}
```

listen_item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem accurately.  The code you show does not have any Buttons.  Do you mean every list item should open a different activity?   Do you mean different instances of the same activity or do you actually have different Activity classes corresponding to the different list items?

Comment: Are you sharing the information you know in a QnA style ?

Comment: have different Activity classes corresponding to the different list items. @DaleWilson

Comment: You are confusing everyone with your "options" thing. The best way is to post your XML code and that will sort the things out.

Comment: Almost Exact question - check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302126/adding-multiple-event-to-listview?rq=1

Comment: @VamsiChalla All the answers didn't work.
And I post the XML.

Comment: @omer341, so you have a listview with textview as an item. 1 row in listview has 1 textview. Is that it?

Comment: @VamsiChalla  Yes. I want every AV extview will lead to another activity.

Comment: @omer341, the answer given by Tenfour04, is also the same as my answer. You can follow any one of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing since you didn't say what went wrong with your code. Maybe the ArrayAdapter is using more than simply a TextView for the layout of each list item, so you can't simply pull the TextView out the way you're doing it.

Try this instead for getting the product string:
`String product = adobe_products[position];`

You will have to make `String[] adobe_products` final.

EDIT:
Based on what I think you're asking, try this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Class<? extends Activity> activityToStart = null;

            switch (position){
            case 0:
                activityToStart = MyProduct0Activity.class;
                break;
            case 1:
                activityToStart = MyProduct1Activity.class;
                break;
            //etc.
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityToStart);
            startActivity(i);

        }  });
```

Comment: In the listview there are many options,Each option will lead to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Okie.. So here is what i understand from your comments. You have a listview and each item in the listview is a textview. And when you click on each item, you need to go to different screen / Activity.

If it is the case...

replace this code

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mavo.class);

                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);

            }
```

with this..

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Switch(position){
case 0:
String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, FIRST_SCREEN.class);
i.putExtra("product", product);
startActivity(i);
break;
case 1:
String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, SECOND_SCREEN.class);
i.putExtra("product", product);
startActivity(i);
break;

// Repeat the same for all screens
...
...
...

}


                }
```

Note ::: I have not tested this code. This is just to give you an idea on how to do it.

Hope this helps..